# Nginx 1.8.0 get location with root to work both with and without trailing slash

Tags: nginx, location, root

I am trying to serve some static content from /data/api folder at /api URL via Nginx. My problem is that any request to /api (without trailing slash) hangs with no access logs at Nginx side. In the same time all requests with trailing slash (e.g. /api/ or /api/index.html) successfully redirects to static resouce folder and works properly.

Dear Nginx guru's, could you, please, help me to understand what is going wrong with my Nging configuration? Here is it:

```
server {

 server_name api.example.com;

 location / {
   return 301 http://www.example.com/;
 }

 location /admin {
   return 404;
 }

 location /v1 {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1;
 }

 location /v1/api {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/schema;
 }

 location /api {
   root /data;
 }

}
```

The main part for this question is last '/api' location but I included the full config here to let you see the whole picture

Comment: I've tried to put 'rewrite ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;' or 'rewrite ^/api$ $schema://$host/api/ permanent;' line appending trailing slash to all requests but that didn't help.

Comment: Is it a real config? It should not hang

Comment: Yes, the only thing I changed is replacing the company name with "example" in config file.